# Populate a JComboBox with an int[]

Tags: java, arrays, swing, int, jcombobox

Is it possible to populate a JComboBox with an int[]? I am writing a code that will use a JComboBox populated with years (in integers).

The code I have written is this:

```
int[] birthYear = new int[currentYear]; //currentYear is an int variable
int inc=1;
for(int i=0;i<currentYear;i++)
{
    birthYear[i]= inc;
    inc++;
}

birthYearBox = new JComboBox(birthYear); //this is the line in which the error occurs
```

I want these to integers in the ComboBox so that I can subtract from them. Do I have to populate the ComboBox with strings, then make them integers after they have been input? Or is there a way to actually populate the ComboBox with the int[]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JCombobox` is generic, but Java generics don't support primitive type (and `int` is a primitive type).

So use an `Integer` array instead :

```
Integer[] birthYear = new Integer[currentYear]; //currentYear is an int variable
int inc=1;
for(int i=0;i<currentYear;i++){
    birthYear[i]= inc;
    inc++;
}
JComboBox<Integer> birthYearBox = new JComboBox<>(birthYear);
```

Answer (score 0):

one alternative if you just want to work with integers:

```
JComboBox<Integer> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();

comboBox.addItem(1);
comboBox.addItem(2);
```

otherwise, you can also try this:

```
String[] birthYear = new String[currentYear]; //currentYear is an int variable
int inc=1;
for(int i=0;i<currentYear;i++)
{
    birthYear[i]= inc + "";
    inc++;
}

birthYearBox = new JComboBox(birthYear);
```

and you can use `Integer.praseInt("1")` to get string representations of a number as a type int if you need it.

hope this helps.